# Scss nested if statements in a function

Tags: css, function, if-statement, sass

I want to pass two values into a function "sprite-chooser()" so that I can choose which sprite to load if it's on a light or dark background. Before I load the sprite I need to check for which UI it is first - so I've got two @if statements and nested @if statements inside but get an error saying: Syntax error: Function sprite-chooser finished without @return.

```
@function sprite-chooser($ui-for, $bg-color) {
    @if ($ui-for == "ui-1") {
        @if (lightness( $bg-color ) > 60 and $ui-for == "ui-1") {
            @return #{$sprite-dark-ui-1};
        }    
        @else {
            @return #{$sprite-light-ui-1};
        }
    }
    @else if ($ui-for == "ui-2") {
        @if (lightness( $bg-color ) > 60 and $ui-for == "ui-2") {
            @return #{$sprite-dark-ui-2};
        }
        @else {
            @return #{$sprite-light-ui-2};
        }
    }
}
```

```
$background-color: #fff;
.class-name {
    background: url(sprite-chooser("ui-1", $background-color)) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another `else` case

```
...
    @else if ($ui-for == "ui-2") {
        @if (lightness( $bg-color ) > 60 and $ui-for == "ui-2") {
            @return #{$sprite-dark-ui-2};
        }
        @else {
            @return #{$sprite-light-ui-2};
        }
    }
    @else { @return null; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zach - I tried that and it now just skip straight to the else.

Comment: @moonunit7 That's because neither of the previous `if` statements were being entered, meaning something is wrong in your setup. This solves your error that you asked about, not the reason why the `if`s don't work (: I'd have to see how you're calling the function to help solve why it's not entering an `if` statement

Comment: I call it like this:
$background-color: #fff;
.class-name {
    background: url(sprite-chooser("ui-1", $background-color)) 0 0 no-repeat;
}